# How can I use the nextJS Cache to update a Page dynamically?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, next.js, fetch

I wanted to see if anyone would help me because I can't get the data to update automatically. The page I'm trying to update is:

[WebAPP Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Qqy5.png)

And here's the code, below the code I explain something important.

```js
import NoEKEY from "@/components/dash/NoEKEY"
import ServerInfoComponent from "@/components/dash/Serverinfo"

const loadData = async () => {
    const res = await fetch(`http://localhost:3000/api/erlc/server`, { cache: 'no-store' })

    if (!res.ok) {
        throw new Error('Failed to fetch data')
    }

    const useData = await res.json()
    console.log(useData)
    return useData
}

async function HomeDashPage() {
    const error = ""

    let data = await loadData()

    return (
        <div>
            <ServerInfoComponent data={data} />
        </div>
    )
}

export default HomeDashPage
```

This code is the one that takes the data and that part works perfectly, the data loads, the problem is that I want to update it without having to refresh the page manually.

If you're wondering why I put it in the cache, it's because of that it doesn't update or reload manually, because it saves the data.

I would appreciate it if anyone can help me a little. THANK YOU.

I tried all searched in google, stackoverflow issues, cache revalidating. But norhing work to update dinamicly the page data.

Comment: How you are updating it ? you mean you wanted to fetch the data automatically every n seconds ?